# extension to default repository class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using the repository pattern with interfaces and I am using structuremap in order to map between them.

In my global.asax I defined:

```
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().Use<EFUnitOfWorkFactory>();
            x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EFRepository<>)
        }
    );
```

Now I want to add another db method to MyEntity entity. So I created MyEntityRepository:

```
class MyEntityRepository:EFRepository<MyEntity>, IMyEntityRepository {
    public void CloseCall(long callId) {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

But now, I forced to add a new line to the initialization of structuremap. I have many cases like this and the number of rows in the initialization of structuremap is getting bigger and bigger.

In addition, most of the cases are one method addition only but this single method addition requires interface for the new repository, implementation in new file and another initialization of structuremap - a lot of work for one method.

How can I solve this?

Am I doing something wrong?

Maybe it is better to use extension metod to Repository (if there is such thing extension to generic..)?

Comment: Will `x.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EFRepository<>)` compile?

Comment: @Bala R: Yes, I already play the application with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Business Tier - where I defined the IRepository interface I have created:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IDataEntity
{
    protected IRepository<T> Repository { get; set; }

    public BaseRepository()
    {
        Repository = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<T>>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQuery()
    {
        return Repository.GetQuery();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetQuery(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        return Repository.GetQuery(includes);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        Repository.Insert(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        Repository.Update(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        Repository.Delete(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Attach(T entity)
    {
        Repository.Attach(entity);
    }
}
```

In the global.asax I have to map the IRepository to the entity framework implementation.
And now for each class I want to expose to the web, I have to define:

```
public class MyEntityRepository: BaseRepository<MyEntity> {
    ....
    Common queries for this entity
    ....
    ....
    overrides of insert, delete and so on
}
```

Now, I can't use the BaseRepository in the web application at all but use the repository that belongs to the entity. I also don't need to register each extension of the repository in structuremap. The only thing is that I have to remember not to use directly the EFRepository (I can get it using the structure map - and I have to avoid using it).

Answer (score 0):

If you have special interfaces which must be resolved with special type you must always write the code somewhere to initialize this. If you don't want to write too much code in your StructureMap initialization use Abstract factory pattern for your DAL layer:

Factory interface:

```
public interface IDalFactory
{
    IXXXRepository XXXRepository { get; }
    IYYYRepository YYYRepository { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class DalFactory : IDalFactory
{
    private IXXXRepository _xxxRepository;
    public IXXXRepository XXXRepository
    {
        return _xxxRepository ?? (_xxxRepository = new XXXRepository());
    }

    private IYYYRepository _yyyRepository;
    public IYYYRepository YYYRepository
    {
        return _yyyRepository ?? (_yyyRepository = new YYYRepository());
    }
}
```

And you will initialize your IoC:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().Use<EFUnitOfWorkFactory>();
            x.For<IDalFactory>().Use<DalFactory>();
        }
    );
```

Specialized code always needs its own registration somewhere unless you build some automatic registration which will search your assemblies with reflection and registers repositories by some naming conventions.

Comment: I am looking for a way I can add new methods to the base repository without have to add 2 new files and other file edit. I am looking a simpler design pattern for extend the base repository and even override its methods sometimes.

Comment: @Naor: You are looking for decorator pattern but still you have to write a new class and new interface.